# Make TrimmedWindow as Application Model

Tags: java, eclipse, modal-dialog, eclipse-rcp, e4

I'm using eclipse e4 and I want to create an application model named TrimmedWindow which I can use as a custom dialog, but I don't want the user to use background windows (block the events) while the dialog is open. Is there any way I can do that with e4?

**[Edit]**

```
@Execute
    public void execute(MApplication application) {
        MTrimmedWindow mWindow = MBasicFactory.INSTANCE.createTrimmedWindow();
        mWindow.setHeight(200);
        mWindow.setWidth(400);
        mWindow.getChildren().add(MBasicFactory.INSTANCE.createPart());
        mWindow.setVisible(true);
        mWindow.setOnTop(true);
        application.getChildren().add(mWindow);
        //how to set application model so that it blocks access to other background windows?

        // SOLUTION
       mWindow.getPersistedState().put(IPresentationEngine.STYLE_OVERRIDE_KEY, String.valueOf(SWT.APPLICATION_MODAL));
    }
```

Comment: You may be able to use [styleOverride](http://blog.vogella.com/2014/03/17/using-eclipse-application-model-persisted-state-to-specify-the-swt-stylebits/)

Comment: @greg-449 Thanks sounds interesting any idea of what I should put in for the value?

Comment: @greg-449 ok found it out it's very simple you just have to insert the value which `System.out.println(SWT.APPLICATION_MODAL)` prints you to the console :)